# Doubt regarding mirrors

Tags: reflection, home-experiment, geometric-optics

This question of mine is regarding some general observation. From ray diagrams it can easily be concluded that using a real object, we cannot get a real image from a plane mirror. But, if we shine a torch on the mirror we see a real image on the wall. Why does a real image form despite ray diagrams showing they do not form?

Comment: Why do you think the "image" formed by the torch on the wall after reflecting off the mirror is "real"?

Comment: Because I can actually see it on the wall

Comment: If you shine a torch onto a mirror you do not create a real image on the wall.  There is no image at all on the wall.   You illuminate the wall, but no image forms. If you stand at the position of the wall and look to the mirror the lens of your eye will produce a real image on your retina of the virtual image formed by the mirror.

Comment: Perhaps you can get a better understanding if you replace the wall by a mirror, and trace the rays in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spot of light on the wall is an image of the bulb in the torch (flashlight for Americans). However, it is an extremely blurry image; you cannot see the shape of the filament inside the bulb on the wall. This is because the aperture of the torch is large.

Look at the picture below. Imagine that the red T on the left is the filament of the torch, the middle lines with a gap are the edges of the torch aperture, and the blurry upside-down T on the right is the image on the wall. The diagonal lines crossing from left to right show the different light rays leaving the filament in differnt directions and still hitting the image plane.

[image: Formation of an image with a pinhole aperture that results in blurring due to the non-zero size of the aperture.]

Because light from a single point on the filament can reach multiple locations on the image plane, the image is blurry since the images of different points on the filament overlap each other. You can imagine that as the aperture in the middle gets larger, the T will become more blurry until it becomes an unrecognizable circle.

The flat mirror does not create the image on the wall, the aperture of the torch does. You can tell this because the spot on the wall is the same whether you shine the torch directly at the wall or by bouncing the light off the flat mirror. In the same way a pinhole camera can create an image, the finite aperture of the torch can create an image of the torch bulb on the wall, blurry though it may be.

If you replaced the torch with a candle or a bare bulb, then no image would form anywhere on a wall after reflecting off the mirror. No optical system (whether lens or aperture) means no image.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the [definition](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Book%3A_Geometric_Optics_(Tatum)/02%3A_Lens_and_Mirror_Calculations/2.03%3A_Real_and_Virtual) of the real image, that is, a real image is formed when the light rays emanating from an object actually converge at a point, we can infer that a plane mirror would always produce a virtual image. This is because light rays from the object (a torch in this case) do not actually converge at a point (see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cogoe.png)).[image]

I believe that it is just a matter of what definition you use to call an image real/virtual. However, another common definition of a real image is that it can be obtained/seen by placing a screen in front of the reflected light. Given your observation that you can "see" the reflected torchlight on a wall/screen, I am not able to reconcile this with the initial [ray-convergence](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Book%3A_Geometric_Optics_(Tatum)/02%3A_Lens_and_Mirror_Calculations/2.03%3A_Real_and_Virtual) definition of a real image.

Comment: He can see the light from the torch that has undergone diffuse reflection from the wall.  He cannot see an image of the torch projected onto the wall

Comment: @garyp Does this answer say otherwise?

Comment: No, it supports my comment. An image forms when rays converge. The rays in case (b) are diverging from a point behind the mirror.  That point is the location of the virtual image of the torch.  Rays do not converge on the wall/mirror, rays continue to diverge.  There is no image on the wall/mirror.   The rays *do* converge if you look towards the virtual image:  the lens of your eye causes the rays to converge on the retina.  That is a real image.